# PG::Error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type time: "2013-03-17"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Trying to save user selected "f.date_select" date attribute to :sizes, :time.

```
PG::Error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type time: "2013-03-17" : INSERT INTO "sizes"
```

The form in: sizes/form.

```
<%= form_for [@user, @size] do |f| %>
...
<%= f.date_select :time, :start_year => 2007, :end_year => 2014 %>
...
<% end %>
```

Migration:

```
 def change
    add_column  :sizes, :time, :date
 end
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with a `date` or `datetime` column ? `time` is [only for hours](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: :time is the columns name, and :date is the column type

Comment: Problem was solved by renaming the time column is sizes table, to something else.
I believe it confused something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer so it might help others:

`time` is a [SQL key word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), and can't be used as a column_name